# redux-toolkit sharing state between reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I building small budget calculator and its the first time i am using redux-toolkit, the problem is
How can share/pass state between reducers in redux-toolkit ? (how can use the totalIncomes and totalExpenses in the balance slice to calculate the total balance ?

another question is is ok to use redux-toolkit instead of plain redux

incomes.js :

```
const incomesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "incomes",
  initialState: {
    list: [],
    loading: false,
    totalIncomes: 0,
    lastFetch: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    ADD_INCOME: (state, action) => {
      state.list.push({
        id: uuidv4(),
        description: action.payload.description,
        amount: action.payload.amount,
      });
    },
    REMOVE_INCOME: (state, action) => {
      const index = state.list.findIndex(
        (income) => income.id === action.payload.id
      );
      state.list.splice(index, 1);
    },
    TOTAL_INCOMES: (state, action) => {
      state.totalIncomes = state.list.reduce(
        (acc, curr) => acc + curr.amount,
        0
      );
    },
  },
});
```

expenses.js :

```
const expensesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "expenses",
  initialState: {
    list: [],
    loading: false,
    totalExpenses: 0,
    lastFetch: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    ADD_EXPENSE: (state, action) => {
      state.list.push({
        id: uuidv4(),
        description: action.payload.description,
        amount: action.payload.amount,
      });
    },
    REMOVE_EXPENSE: (state, action) => {
      const index = state.list.findIndex(
        (expense) => expense.id === action.payload.id
      );
      state.list.splice(index, 1);
    },
    TOTAL_EXPENSES: (state, action) => {
      state.totalExpenses = state.list.reduce(
        (acc, curr) => acc + curr.amount,
        0
      );
    },
  },
});

export const {
  ADD_EXPENSE,
  REMOVE_EXPENSE,
  TOTAL_EXPENSES,
} = expensesSlice.actions;
export default expensesSlice.reducer;
```

balance.js :

```
const balanceSlice = createSlice({
  name: "balance",
  initialState: {
    total: 0
  },
  reducers: {
    CALC_TOTAL: (state, action) => {
      // How to Calculate this ?
    },
  },
});enter code here

export const { CALC_TOTAL } = balanceSlice.actions;
export default balanceSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking into this - author's is the wrong approach to using redux for state management.

When using redux you want your state as normalized as possible - you shouldn't store uneeded/duplicated state or state that can be calculated based on other state, in this example there's no need to save totalIncomes since we can calculate this based on the list of incomes (same goes for totalExpenses and balance).

As mentioned, the totalIncomes shouldn't be part of the state but should be a calculated value, you can either calculate it on the fly or use a selector. In the below example I'll use a selector.

**Redux Toolkit solution**

To use it with Redux toolkit it might look something like this, I've removed parts of code for brewity:

incomes slice

```
// ...

const incomesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "incomes",
  initialState: {
    list: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    ADD_INCOME: (state, action) => {
      state.list.push({
        id: uuidv4(),
        description: action.payload.description,
        amount: action.payload.amount,
      });
    },
    REMOVE_INCOME: (state, action) => {
      const index = state.list.findIndex(
        (income) => income.id === action.payload.id
      );
      state.list.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
});


export const getTotalIncome = createSelector(
    totalIncomeSelector,
    calculateTotalIncome,
);

export function totalIncomeSelector(state) {
    return state.incomes.list;
}

export function calculateTotalIncome(incomesList) {
    return incomesList.reduce((total, income) => total + income.amount);    
}

export const {
    ADD_INVOICE,
    REMOVE_INVOICE,
} = incomesSlice.actions;

export default incomesSlice.reducer;
```

expenses slice - removed parts for brewity

```
// ...

const expensesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "expenses",
  initialState: {
    list: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    ADD_EXPENSE: (state, action) => {
      state.list.push({
        id: uuidv4(),
        description: action.payload.description,
        amount: action.payload.amount,
      });
    },
    REMOVE_EXPENSE: (state, action) => {
      const index = state.list.findIndex(
        (income) => income.id === action.payload.id
      );
      state.list.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
});


export const getTotalExpense = createSelector(
    totalExpenseSelector,
    calculateTotalExpense,
);

export function totalExpenseSelector(state) {
    return state.expenses.list;
}

export function calculateTotalExpenseexpenseList) {
    return expensesList.reduce((total, expense) => total + expense.amount); 
}

export const {
    ADD_EXPENSE,
    REMOVE_EXPENSE,
} = expensesSlice.actions;

export default expensesSlice.reducer;
```

balance slice - you don't really need a slice here, you just need a selector

```
import { getTotalIncome, totalIncomeSelector } from './incomeSlice';
import { getTotalExpense, totalExpenseSelector } from './expenseSlice';

export const getBalance = createSelector(
    getTotalIncome,
    getTotalExpense,
    (totalIncome, totalExpense) => totalIncome - totalIncome,
);
```

Example component

```
// ...

function BalanceComponent({
    totalIncome,
    totalExpense,
    balance,
}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Finance overview</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Total Income:</span>
                <span>{totalIncome}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Total Expense:</span>
                <span>{totalExpense}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Balance:</span>
                <span>{balance}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        totalIncome: getTotalIncome(state),
        totalExpense: getTotalExpense(state),
        balance: getBalance(state),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BalanceComponent);
```

**Note:** In the question the author seems to be breaking up his state into too many slices, all this can be a lot simpler by having it all as a single slice. That's what I would do.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ok to use redux-toolkit instead of plain redux

**YES**. It was originally created to help address common concerns about Redux. See its [purpose](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/quick-start#purpose).

> How can share/pass state between reducers in `redux-toolkit`?

1. You can pass the used state parts to `action.payload`.

```
dispatch(CALC_TOTAL(totalIncomes,totalExpenses))
```

2. You can use `extraReducers` and "listen" to to your incomes/expenses changes.
3. You can create a middleware or use `createAsyncThunk` where you can reference the most updated state with `getState()`.

   - Toolkit [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/).

Comment: can you please give me an example of the 'extraReducer' ? and which method use suggest ?

Comment: You have good examples in the docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice, if you want a specific one, please create a producible example ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq))

Comment: Always go for is the most readable solution, it depends on the situation - as it seems like beginners question just pass relevant state to payload (1).

Comment: ,  CALC_TOTAL: (state, action) => {
      // How to Calculate this ?
    }, i leave this empty ?

Comment: even if a pass the payload its updated only in the second time (delay)

Comment: No one can’t guess without producible example

Comment: i am new to this redux stuff so i dont now how to create producible example. but i tried to do something like this (in the CALC_TOTAL): state.total = action.payload.incomes - action.payload.expenses , and then dispatch like this :   dispatch(CALC_TOTAL({ 
incomes: totalIncomes, expenses: totalExpenses})). and the results is that its update only in the second times(

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you have enough material to create a minimal example which works, without it - it is just assumptions and not straight answers. I can't help you any further.